# Injecting specific objects into specific constructors with Guice

Tags: java, singleton, guice

I am constructing a variable amount of KlasseA-objects and a corresponding amount of KlasseB-objects.

KlasseA depends on ClassZ and ClassY, KlasseB depends on ClassZ, ClassY and KlasseA. KlasseA & KlasseB have to use the same instance of ClassY since it has an external connection which has to be used by both classes. BUT when I create another pair of KlasseA & KlasseB objects both have to use a new instance of ClassY, since they may not use the same connection as the other 2 KlasseA & KlasseB objects.

So far I have used Guice to inject the dependencies, but since Guice would either always create a new instance of ClassY or only one instance if I make it a singleton, it doesnt really work as I intended.

Now I am wondering whether there is a possibility to do this with Guice or if I should rather take a different approach, like

```
@Inject
public KlasseA(ClassZ classZ, ClassY classY)
{
    classZ = classZ;
    classY = classY;
}

@Inject
public KlasseB(ClassZ classZ, KlasseA klasseA)
{
    classZ = classZ;
    classY = klasseA.getClassY();
    klasseA = klasseA;
}
```

This way definitely works, but it kinda feels like a small hack, so I am wondering if someone has a better solution or something inspiring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently a clean, Guice-compliant solution can be achieve through the use of a factory

```
@Inject
public KlasseA(ClassZ classZ, ClassY classY)
{
    classZ = classZ;
    classY = classY;
}

@Inject
public KlasseB(ClassZ classZ, KlasseA klasseA, @Assisted ClassYFactory classyFactory)
{
    classZ = classZ;
    classY = classyFactory.create(klasseA);
    klasseA = klasseA;
}
```

So it's still Guice handling the dependency.